# Why is my D7100's auto focus not working?

Tags: autofocus, troubleshooting, nikon-d7100

Recently my Nikon D7100 has stopped auto focusing. It's with the AF-S 50mm f/1.8G lens (my only lens). Yes, all the switches are set to auto, and I've done a reset. The autofocus assist light doesn't light up either.

Think it's safe to say that it is busted? Or is it possible that I'm missing something?

Comment: See [What should I do when my Nikon AF-S lens won't auto focus?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20624/what-should-i-do-when-my-nikon-af-s-lens-wont-auto-focus) and [What can I do if autofocus does not work but manual focus does?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/30470/what-can-i-do-if-autofocus-does-not-work-but-manual-focus-does) or maybe [Why does my Nikon D3100 no longer auto-focus via the viewfinder?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/21795/why-does-my-nikon-d3100-no-longer-auto-focus-via-the-viewfinder) or the other two dozen questions we have on this topic.

Comment: I already went through them, which is why I posted a new question asking if someone had another thought for something I might have overlooked. the only thing i hadn't tried was cleaning the contacts. Did that this morning, and it didn't seem to help. But, interestingly, auto-focus seems to be working again - thought I am not sure why.

Comment: Try a different lens.

Comment: Sounds like cleaning the contacts _was_ the answer, even if it didn't seem to help immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with dpollitt. Trying another lens will tell you if it's a camera body fault or a lens fault. If there's a camera store nearby, I'm sure they'd let you borrow a lens for a moment to test it.