# Nikon D7100 not Auto-Focusing

Tags: nikon, dslr, autofocus, repair

I've had a Nikon D7100 for about 6 years and have always used the Nikon 18-55mm AF-S lens that came with it. I've never had any problems with the camera. I've also never taken off this lens for the 6 years I've had the camera.

Recently, I got a Nikon 50mm f/1.8G AF-S lens. After I took off the original 18-55mm lens to attach this new 50mm, the Autofocus stopped working.

I checked all of the focusing switches (both the one on the body and the lens) and all are in the correct positions (AF and M/A). I also reset the camera's settings, but it still didn't work.

Then, I switched back to the original 18-55mm (which had been working perfectly before) to see if it's the lens or the body that is causing the problem. But now, the original 18-55mm won't autofocus either (again, all switches are in correct place).

I've looked through all of the related questions on this website, as well as other websites. But I can't find any answer for how to fix this. I also tried cleaning the contacts, but no progress. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my D7100's auto focus not working?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/why-is-my-d7100s-auto-focus-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things you can try.

- Make sure the lens is fully seated and when you rotate it you hear the lens release button click (page 27 in your manual). If you can remove your lens without pressing the lens release button, your lens isn't mounted properly.
- Check the focus mode switches on the body and lens (you indicate you have done this). You may want to flick the switches to manual and back to auto in case the switch contacts are dirty.
- Make sure the lens contacts are clean (you indicate you have done this).
- Reset the camera to factory defaults (see page 131 in your manual). This may clear up a menu setting that was inadvertently set.

Comment: Thanks qrk! Taking your advice, I checked to see if my lens was on properly by rotating it without pressing the lens release button. Then I heard a click. Turns out, I hadn't been properly attaching the lenses (since I've never done this in the 6 years I've had my camera)! Great answer (sorry I can't upvote), thanks a lot!